# Different reference returned from Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, process, reference, taskmanager

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(BatchFile)

Process p = Process.Start(psi)
```

Why `p.ID` is different than process id visible in WindowsTaskManager

(`BatchFile` is path to external program with appropriate parameters)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316596/system-diaganostics-process-id-isnt-the-same-process-id-shown-in-task-manger-wh

Comment: do you mean `Process p = Process.Start(psi);` ?

Comment: To clarify, is BatchFile an actual executable or is it a batch-file in the "normal" sense (i.e. a script which calls other executables, one of which is the one you're interested in?). If it's the former, then it should be as you expect. However, if it's the latter, then the process id will be that of the process executing the script, which then kicks off the program of interest, which will have a different id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process ID is only meaningful while the process is alive. The first thing to check is `.HasExited` - if this is true, ***ignore*** the process ID; it no longer has any meaning.

There are a number of ways you can start something and have no process left *even though you can apparently see it still on screen*:

- if it is a script/bat/cmd that spawns something *and exits* (remember: you are watching the script, not the "something")
- if the exe does some inter-exe voodoo internally - for example, most of the office apps and internet explorer do this; if there is an existing process, it forwards the args to *that* process to handle, and exits immediately

Comment: Accurate observation about HasExited. But finally how can I run external program and to catch its id?

Comment: @Saint_pl if your launcher is exiting, then you'll have to find it the hard way... or: don't use the launcher (some apps allow you to add switches to say "don't do that", but that is entirely usage-specific)

Comment: Solution is CommandLine and specyfic name of the file *.jou to recognize the running process

Answer (score 2):

I assume BatchFile is some kind of cmd or bat file that runs other processes one by one.
So in Windows Task Manager you actually see ids of those processes that are run by batch file.

Examples

If I do this

```
 var p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

`p.Id` will match to the `PID` from Task Manager.

However, if I do this:

```
 var p = Process.Start("test.cmd"); // test.cmd has notepad.exe call inside
```

`p.Id` will be different from `PID` shown in the Task Manager.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that it's because `p.ID` is the id of the process that's running the batch file rather than the id of the process started *by* the batch file.

You can start the executable directly by `Process.Start` by using the [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Comment: No, ID in TaskManager is completely different and do not fit into any process in TaskManager

Comment: @Saint_pl - if the batch file just starts another exe then it's process won't last long so you might not see it the Task Manager.

Comment: If I understand correctly - p.ID is id of running batchfile (e.g. "start.bat") ? Not this program that is run from inside of this start.bat?

Comment: @ChrisF - But if I use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx as you proposed I still get different p.ID that that in TaskManager

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\MyProgram.exe", @"abc -i jouFile.jou");